# Some parts of my regular expression not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression to validate the input on a textbox

The expression should allow only numbers, maxmium two decimals, max one comma (,) and one minus symbol in front of the number (optional).

Valid:

- 0,25
- 10,2
- -7000
- -175,33
- 15555555555555,99

invalid:

- 9,999
- 15.03
- 77,77,77
- etc

I'm using `^[-+]?[\d ]+(,\d{0,2})?$`
The regex is used in a Jquery code to prevent the user from entering invalid numbers (event.preventDefault()):

```
    $("input[name*='TB_mytbx']").on('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[-+]?[\d ]+(,\d{0,2})?$", "g");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Only a part of the regular expression seems to work.**

It works with numbers (It does not allow me to enter letters) but it also won't allow commas (,) and the minus (-).

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

Before I used:

```
    if (focused.val().indexOf(',') != -1) {
    var number = (focused.val().split(','));
    if (number[1] && number[1].length >= 2) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
```

But this gives annoying behavior. As soon as you enter a number with two digits you can't make edits anymore. For example: you can't change 200,50 to 300,50 or 100 300,50. (You get the point). I hoped that a regex could change that somehow.

Comment: I think you're massively over-complicating the regex. This should be plenty: `^-?\d+(,\d\d)?$`

Comment: And always use double escaping ``\`` inside string patterns. Or use regex literal notation, `/.../`. And do not use `g` modifier when using patterns with `RegExp#test`.

Comment: You're testing the key that was pressed instead of the value of the input.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Yes. To prevent the user from entering it. Check the jquery code.

Comment: @Enrico I know, but the regex is build for a value (like 15.03) but not for a charcode. If you don't want some keys to be pressed, check either the keycodes (like is the key equal to the comma etc) or the value of the input field.

Comment: @Enrico yes but you test your regex on the only last char pressed instead of the whole input value, this way, it is normal that it won't let you enter `-`, because it would never satisfy the regex, it would need a number too (you would need a special test to let user enter - first before testing your whole regex on the input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who wanna know, I solved it using this code

```
        $("input[name*='mythingy']").on('keypress', function (event) {
        var theEvent = event || window.event;
        var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
        key = String.fromCharCode(key);
        var value = this.value;
        var value = value.replace(value.substring(theEvent.currentTarget.selectionStart, theEvent.currentTarget.selectionEnd), "");
        value = [value.slice(0, theEvent.currentTarget.selectionStart), key, value.slice(theEvent.currentTarget.selectionStart)].join('');
        var regex = /^[-+]?([\d ]+(,\d{0,2})?)?$/;
        if (!regex.test(value)) {
            theEvent.returnValue = false;
            if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're massively over-complicating the regex. This should be plenty:

```
^-?\d+(,\d\d)?$
```

- `^` Start of line,
- `-?` Optional minus sign,
- `\d+` Followed by a bunch of digits,
- `(,\d\d)?` Followed by a comma and 2 digits, which are all 3 optional.
  <sup>(alternative: `(,\d{2})?`)</sup>
- `$` End of line.

```js
var regex = /^-?\d+(,\d\d)?$/;

console.log(regex.test('0,25'));
console.log(regex.test('-175,33'));
console.log(regex.test('15555555555555,99'));

console.log(regex.test('9,999'));
console.log(regex.test('15.03'));
console.log(regex.test('77,77,77'));
```

There you have a regex to validate the input value.
Now, that block of code can be replaced with this:

```
$("input[name*='TB_mytbx']").on('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = /^-?\d+(,\d\d)?$/;
    var value = $(this).val();  // Use the field's value, instead of the pressed key.

    if (!regex.test(value)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `(,\d\d)?` part be better written as `(,\d{2})`?

Comment: Simple but elegant regex pattern, great one ^^

Comment: @chsdk: define "better". In this specific case, `\d\d` is 1 character shorter than `\d{2}`. Both are valid approaches. I think that `\d\d` is slightly easier on the eyes, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus It doesn't take anything from your Regex (which is awesome), just an optimisation, maybe for readability :) But don't take me wrong it's worth a +1.

Comment: @chsdk: my point is that "optimisation" is in the eye of the beholder on this one. (Unless `{2}` is actually faster? Dunno...)

Comment: That still allows a user to enter invalid values (15,254). As soon as this happens the entire thing 'blocks'. Forcing the user to backspace the last character.

Comment: @Enrico: That's not a problem with the regex, but with the way you handle invalid input... I fixed the regex, but if you want invalid input to be handled differently, you'd have to change what's in the `if`.

Comment: @Enrico look at my other comment, even with a valid regex, it won't let you enter `-` to start, because checking at every character, it wouldn't satisfy the whole regex that needs at least a number

Comment: @Enrico:  the test would return false for `''`, `'-'`, `'-1,'`, `'-1,0'` and `true` for `'-1'`, `'-1,00'`. So it's best used to validate the field, not to block input. (So to show a red border / block submit)